# VBA code to update a column on Workbook_Open

Tags: excel, vba

I've been muddling my way through a bit of VBA to improve a request tracker we use at my place of work having done some VB.NET a decade or so ago in Highschool. Trial and error with some googling to find answers when I'm stuck has served me well but I cannot for the life of me figure this one out...

I want to run some code when the workbook is opened to update cells in a specific column. I got this to work on the Worksheet_Change event but that would be running it too often and as the number of records grows I fear it would slow things down.

My problem is that I do not know the syntax to reference the column when I am not in the worksheet code. My (feeble) attempt was as follows:

```
            Private Sub Workbook_Open()
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2016").Columns(10).Value = "x" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2016").Columns(11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2016").Columns(7).Value, Date) - 1
                End If
            End Sub
```

The idea is that if Column J contains an x Column K should display the number of working days between the value in Column G (date request was logged) and today's date so that it shows how long the request has been outstanding

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of macro, it can be done by using the below formula

```css
=IF(J1="x",NETWORKDAYS(G1,TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy"))-1)
```

If you want to be done via macro only the hope the code will help you :)

```css
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
l = Sheets("2016").Columns(10).End(xlDown).Row
For c = 1 To l
If Cells(c, 10).Value <> "" Then
a = Sheets("2016").Cells(c, 7).Value
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "mm/dd/yyy")
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2016").Cells(c, 10).Value = "x" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2016").Cells(c, 11).Value = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(a, b) - 1
    End If
End If
Next c
End Sub
```

If you want to address any cell in a specific column please use **cells(row_no, col_no)**